# Extraer datos de Json y mostrarlos en HTML

Tags: php, html, json

Tengo una consulta, tengo un sensor que instalé de temperatura y quiero extraer los datos de JSON en una tabla HTML. Si yo ingreso a la IP http://10.64.1.113/getSensor me trae estos datos :

```
{"hum":"42","temp":"18.7","Conectado":1,"ThermocloudOnline":1}
```

Cree el siguiente JS y lo `*linkie* a un HTML:

```js
const request = new XMLHttpRequest (); 
      
     request.open ('GET', 'http://10.64.1.113/getSensor'); 
     request.send (); 
      
     request.onload = () => { 
       if (request.status === 200) { 
         console.log ("Success"); // So extract data from json and create table 
         
         // Extracting data 
         var jokeid = JSON.parse (request.response) .value.temp; 
         var joke = JSON.parse (request.response) .value.hum; 
         
         // Creating table 
         var table = "<table>"; 
     table + = "<tr> <td> Temperatura </td> <td> Humedad </td> </tr>"; 

     table + = "</table>"; 
      
         // Showing the table inside table 
         document.getElementById ("mydiv"). innerHTML = table; 
       } 
     }; 
      
     request.onerror = () => { 
       console.log ("error") 
     };
```

Y en el HTML puse lo siguiente:

```html
< div id="mydiv" >  < /div >
```

Pero me tira error al ingresar, que estoy haciendo mal ? .

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué errores tienes? Recuerda el [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen) que se menciona en el [tour] y en [ask].

Comment: Hola! Gracias por responder, intente lo siguiente. crear un .JS. Edito el post y lo agrego!

Comment: ¿Primero envías la petición y luego agregas los listeners?.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour].Mencionas que hay un error, pero no indicas cuál es y, como puedes comprender, esta información es vital para poder entender cuál es el problema y probablemente sea el punto de partida para que un experto en tema pueda ayudarte a resolver la situación en que te encuentras. De otra forma, se hace muy difícil responderte. Encontrarás más información en [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Como en las etiquetas pones que lo quieres con PHP. Te daré una forma fácil de hacerlo.

```
<?php

    $json = '{"hum":"42","temp":"18.7","Conectado":1,"ThermocloudOnline":1}';

    // Así se obtiene un objeto stdClass.
    $r1 = json_decode($json);
    echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($r1);
    echo '</pre>';
    echo 'Temperatura es: '.$r1->temp;

    echo '<br>****************';
    // Así se obtiene un Array Asociativo.
    $r2 = json_decode($json, true);
    echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($r2);
    echo '</pre>';
    echo 'Temperatura es: '.$r2['temp'];
    echo '<br>****************';
```

Y una tabla básica de HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Parser</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Jquery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- CSS Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Humedad</th>
                <th>Temperatura</th>
                <th>Conectado</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $r1->hum; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $r1->temp; ?></td>
                <td><?php
                    if ($r1->Conectado == 1) {
                        echo 'Conectado';
                    }
                    else{
                        echo 'No Conectado';
                    }
                ?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Temperaturas]

Es obvio que si en el JSON vienen varios datos, luego de crear el array lo tendrás que iterar con un `foreach` y quedará algo mas o menos así.

```
<?php

    $json = '{
        "salon1":{"name":"Alfa","hum":"42","temp":"18.7","Conectado":1,"ThermocloudOnline":1},
        "salon2":{"name":"Bravo","hum":"45","temp":"19.7","Conectado":0,"ThermocloudOnline":3},
        "salon3":{"name":"Charlie","hum":"47","temp":"21.7","Conectado":1,"ThermocloudOnline":2}
    }';

    // Así se obtiene un objeto stdClass.
    $r1 = json_decode($json);
```

Y el HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Parser</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Jquery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- CSS Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Salon</th>
                <th>Humedad</th>
                <th>Tenmperatura</th>
                <th>Conectado</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
                foreach ($r1 as $salon => $datos) {
            ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $datos->name; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $datos->hum; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $datos->temp; ?></td>
                        <td><?php
                            if ($datos->Conectado == 1) {
                                echo 'Conectado';
                            }
                            else{
                                echo 'No Conectado';
                            }
                        ?></td>
                    </tr>
            <?php
                }
            ?>

        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Temps2]

Comment: Gracias OCHOA, pero como le digo al PHP que el dato lo tiene que sacar de esta URL http://10.64.1.113/getSensor .... Como es un aparato que lee la temp,

Comment: Esa es una pregunta diferente. Te sugiero hagas otra publicación preguntando eso. PD: Eso se haría con cURL o  API :-)

Answer (score 0):

Para los que no sepan encontré la solución, dejo el código por si alguien lo necesita:

```
<?php
    $url = "http://10.64.1.113/getSensor";

    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    if($e=curl_error($curl)){
        echo $e;
    }else{
        $json=json_decode($resp, true);

        $nTemperatura=$json['temp'];
        $nHumedad    =$json['hum'];
    }

    curl_close($curl);
?>
```